# Java class validating a Pattern expression compile

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I've written a really simple regular expression to validate a phone number that I can see works in the engine provided by zytrax.com regex.  When I use it in the class to compile as a pattern I get en error with the escaped characters for the Pattern.compile string to process.

```
package Test;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class FindMainTestExcercisePN {
private static String phone;
private static Matcher matcher;

private boolean getCheckNumber(String pn) {
    boolean valid = matcher.matches();      
    return valid;
}
private void PhoneNumber(String input) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?:(?:\\+?\\s*1\\s*(?:[.-\\s*]?)(?:[.\\s*-]?))?(?:(\\s*([0-9]|[0-9]|[0-9])\\s*)|([0-9]|[0-9]|[0-9]))\\s*(?:[.-\\s*]?)?)?([0-9]|[0-9]|[0-9]{2})\\s*(?:[.\\s*-]?)(?:[.-\\s*]?)?([0-9]|[0-9]|[0-9]|[0-9]{4})\\s*");
    matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
}
public static void main(String[] a) {
FindMainTestExcercisePN ex15 = new FindMainTestExcercisePN();
phone = "1-098-234-5454";
ex15.PhoneNumber(phone);
boolean bool = ex15.getCheckNumber(phone);  
System.out.println("The number is valid= " + bool);
}
}
```

If you take out the escapes it will work just fine (prime ex. 1-345-345-3324) so any suggestions please?

Comment: Honestly? Don't use regex to validate telephone numbers. Use a proper library like Google's libphonenumber. Just because a number matches your pattern doesn't mean it's a valid phone number. This pattern also falls flat on its face if you ever have to handle a non-US phone number because many of them don't follow the same format, they may have more or fewer digits, not use hyphens, etc...

Comment: You asked for a suggestion, I provided one: use the appropriate tool for the job. Believe it or not, using the appropriate tool will *save you time*. Complex regular expressions are non-trivial to write and a complete pain in the backside to maintain when you come back to it even a few days later. They're also not sufficient for properly validating telephone numbers, even without taking international phone numbers into consideration. I know. I had to add phone number validation to an application last year.

Comment: Look there are a thousand ways to validate a phone number. I could use Struts 2, JavaScript, etc.  I wanted a pure non-enterprise level java class Pattern matcher to validate with the standards I would accept.  It is trivial even not taking international phone numbers into consideration.

Comment: But that's the thing - telephone numbers don't follow a pattern. They follow a *format*, and there's a difference between a *format* and a *pattern*. Regex is appropriate for one and not the other. Most third party libraries are non-enterprise so using them wouldn't go against that rule. However, if you think that validating telephone numbers using regex is trivial, I'm afraid you haven't understood the task. Regex can tell you if the input matches a specific pattern - it can't tell you if the input is a valid US telephone number.

Answer (score 1):

This expression is illegal:

```
[.-\\s*]
```

In a character class, the dash character is a range operator, eg `[0-9]` means "any character in the range 0 to 9"., but here you have coded a range `.-\s`, which attempts to express "any character in the range dot to 'any whitespace'", which is clearly nonsense.

To code a *literal* dash in a character class, code it *first* or *last*.

If the intention if this expression is "a dot, dash, whitespace or star", then code:

```
[.\\s*-]
```

If the star is not intended as a literal, but you want to express "a dot or dash, *or* any number of whitespace", use this:

```
([.-]?|\\s*)
```

Answer (score -1):

you method getCheckNumber always return true

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Right because it throws the Pattern Exception for compiling the Pattern. I just generically assinged true to debug in give test class as the package is called.